# Генерация рандомного треугольника

Tags: python, tuple, generate

Есть такая задача:
Написать функцию, которая создает треугольник на плоскости со случайными координатами в виде кортежа ((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)). В функции должна быть проверка, чтобы три точки не лежали на одной прямой.

Ниже мой код генерации координат:

```
import random
    
def f():
    coords = tuple([(random.uniform(-100, 100), random.uniform(-100, 100)) for i in range(3)])
    return coords
```

Не могу сообразить как написать проверку, что точки не лежат на одной прямой. Может быть как-то через расчет площади треугольника?

Comment: Строите уравнение прямой через две точки и проверяете третью лежит ли на ней, получается ли тождество

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x1*(y2-y3) + x2*(y3-y1) + x3*(y1-y2) == 0
```

Просто вычисляем площадь(удвоенную) треугольника, и если она нулевая - значит он вам не подходит =)

---

Или из уравнения прямой легко выводится тождество:

```
(y1-y2)(x1-x3) == (y1-y3)(x1-x2)
```

На самом деле, математически способы эквивалентны в точности до перестановки точек =)

*На практике, вам придётся работать с плавающими запятыми. Стало быть сравнивать числа нужно с этой оговоркой. `abs(V) < eps`*

Comment: Спасибо. Можете показать сам вывод тождества из уравнения прямой.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qbK8WDjR

Comment: Спасибо. То есть если (y1-y2)(x1-x3) == (y1-y3)(x1-x2) обе стороны равны, значит точки лежат на прямой?

Comment: На самом деле, не всегда) Проверять случаи x1=x2=x3 и y1=y2=y3 всё равно нужно

Answer (score 2):

уравнение прямой:

```
y = ax + b
```

имея 2 точки вы можете вычислить коэффициенты `(a, b)`, а на 3 точке проверить - если подставить `x, y` в уравнение, то обратится ли оно в 0 или нет - это и будет проверка на то, лежат ли 3 точки на 1 прямой

единственное, что надо учесть, что прямая может быть вертикальной или горизонтальной :)

Answer (score 2):

Тождество на проверку

(Y3-Y1)/(Y2- Y1)-(X3-X1)/(X2-X1)=0

[Ссылка](http://www.cleverstudents.ru/line_and_plane/line_passes_through_2_points.html) на уравнение

Уравнение прямой проходящей через две точки

Comment: y2!=y1 и x2!=x1

Comment: Спасибо. Если 0, значит точки на одной прямой? Это уравнение стандартное, или вы сами вывели его? Если стандартное, киньте ссылку, пожалуйста

Comment: @faceVB уравнение выводится на коленке из уравнения прямой при нахождении коэффициента `a` уравнения `y = ax + b`

Comment: Является ответом